# Почему виджеты Яндекс.Карт не отображаются в мобильной версии сайта? WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, яндекс-карты

Размещаю виджет организации отзывов организации с `Яндекс.Карт` при помощи элемента `"HTML-код"` на движке `WordPress`. В версии для компьютеров отображается карта, а в мобильной остаётся ссылка. Пробовал сменить тему сайта; разместить виджет другой организации, которая работает [на сайте примере](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/vidzhet-otzyvov-dobavte-otzyvy-s-yandeks-kart-na-svoy-sayt) — тоже не работает. Из этого рискну предположить, что проблема именно в моей версии сайта или где-то в движке `WordPress`. Писал в поддержку Яндекса, говорят, что тема `WordPress-а` может оставлять только ссылку сайта или что-то вроде того: проблема не у них.

HTML код карты, который я вствляю в страницу:

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;"><a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/org/katervspb_com/27303910302/?utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:0px;">Katervspb.com</a><a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/2/saint-petersburg/category/boats_motor_boats_yachts/184107329/?utm_medium=mapframe&utm_source=maps" style="color:#eee;font-size:12px;position:absolute;top:14px;">Катера, лодки, яхты в Санкт‑Петербурге</a><iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CCU4zGgCXC" width="560" height="400" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen="true" style="position:relative;"></iframe></div>
```

[image: WordPress]

[image: ПК]

[image: Мобильная Версия]